# unrecognized expression: a[href=#!]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Na URL, se eu deixar somente `dominio.com.br` o site funciona normalmente, se eu colocar `dominio.com.br/#` continua funcionando também, mas ao colocar `dominio.com.br/#!` o site me retorna este erro

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#!]

no arquivo jQuery (1.9.0).

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Já tentou com outra versão do jQuery? Uma mais recente?

Comment: Você já viu em algum lugar isso funcionando?

Comment: Você está pegando a url e passando para alguma função ou algo assim?

Comment: Ao meu ver, seria o correto dar um erro assim, porque logo após o # costuma tentar acessar um lugar dentro do html que contenha o id... ex: `are.html?#id-3434` daí seta a tela para a altura daquele lugar por exemplo uma div com id="id-3434" e nesse caso o problema é que `!` não é válido para um id

Comment: Já tentei com várias versões do IE, da 1.8.2 até a 1.11.0.

Comment: Pode ser um plugin que gerencie histório de navegação. Você poderia fornecer mais detalhes, quais plugins e/ou frameworks js está usando, se o seu próprio código tenta fazer algo com a URL, etc? Da maneira como está, não dá para responder sua pergunta, e ela precisaria ser fechada.

Answer (score 0):

O jQuery está tentando utilizar a porção final da URL como ID em uma query, mas não há um elemento com essa ID ("!") na página, por isso o jQuery lança o erro.
Você tem que se certificar de que o elemento EXISTE no corpo da página, e que ele possui um ID válido, que possa ser referenciado na URL.

Comment: É verdade, também acho que é isso que está acontecendo. Mas o jQuery não faz isso sozinho. Ou tem um plugin tentando usar parte do hash como ID, ou é código que o próprio autor da pergunta escreveu. Mas não dá pra afirmar qual desses dois é o caso, pois o autor não forneceu informações suficientes.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Eu ia até chutar que era algum plugin de rolagem suave, mas aí li que não era para responder na base do "eu acho que"... haha!

Comment: Na verdade não foi eu que desenvolvi o código jquery, eu peguei esse código pronto, e nele está sendo usado vários plugins, eu também estou no "achômetro" que é algum plugin, mas não consigo identificar qual é, vou continuar procurando, caso encontre eu posto aqui. obrigado a todos.

Comment: @RodrigoGalter Bom ter um feedback seu, achei que você tinha abandonado a pergunta. Olha, como está, é bem capaz que ela seja fechada mesmo. Mas se posteriormente você editá-la com mais informações (mesmo fechada), ela pode ser reaberta. Se precisar de ajuda com isso no futuro, me procure aqui no site.